# Blazor How to Authorize Based on RoleClaims

Tags: permissions, authorization, blazor

I am implementing the User Role management, also, I have Role Permission (RoleClaims) setting.

The idea is user with specific roles will get access based on the permission/claims of those roles.

For API endpoint, I already implemented but I am not sure how to just render the authorized html in blazor.

Here is the code I try but it doesn't works as follow:

```
    @page "/product"
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

<h1>Product Management</h1>
<br />



<AuthorizeView Policy="@Permissions.Products.View">
        <button class="btn btn-success">View</button>
    </AuthorizeView>

    <AuthorizeView Policy="@Permissions.Products.Edit">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
    </AuthorizeView>

    <AuthorizeView Policy="@Permissions.Products.Delete">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Delete</button>
    </AuthorizeView>

// Option 2 --- User is not found error

@*@if ((AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Permissions.Products.Create)).Result.Succeeded)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    }
    @if ((AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Permissions.Products.View)).Result.Succeeded)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-info">View</button>
    }
    @if ((AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Permissions.Products.Edit)).Result.Succeeded)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Modify</button>
    }
    @if ((AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Permissions.Products.Delete)).Result.Succeeded)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    }*@

@code {

}
```

Method return currentuser with claims

```
 [HttpGet]
    public CurrentUser CurrentUserInfo()
    {
        return new CurrentUser
        {
            IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
            UserName = User.Identity.Name,
            Claims = User.Claims.ToDictionary(c => c.Type, c => c.Value)
        };    
    }
```

My RoleClaims table

[image]

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: yes. i think i did.

Comment: could you help me with this question of mine, it falls into the same area if you dont mind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950204/blazor-webassembly-how-to-create-policy-based-authorization

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72960150/3036876